# css background-image changed with javascript rollover innerhtml

Tags: javascript

I'm doing an assignment for my course and need to change an image - which is a css background-image - with javascript. What I'd really like is to have some text pop up on top of the image when the mouse rolls over the image. I'm trying this:

```
function mouseRollover(MyImage)
{
    MyImage.getElementById('picture1').innerHTML = "Aphex Twin";
    }
```

And in my html document I have a div with the id of 'picture1' which I also have onmouseover and onmouseout with the names of the functions.

But I'm being told that "Unable to get property 'getElementById' of undefined or null reference" So the "getElementById" doesn't seem to be able to do what I need. Is there some way to use innerHTML to put words on top of an image?

Comment: you can use title attribute for that: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you implement the mouse event handler registering. The root cause of "Unable to get property 'getElementById' of undefined or null reference" error is wrong DOM reference. If mouseRollover is an evnet listener, "MyImage" will be a event object. You should use "event.target" or "event.srcElement" (depends on browser) to get DOM reference then manipulate it. Try to implement like this way:

HTML

```
<div id="picture1" class="dynamic-img"></div>
<div id="picture2" class="dynamic-img"></div>
```

CSS

```
#picture1{
width:512px;
height:349px;
background-image: url(http://www.vetprofessionals.com/catprofessional/images/home-cat.jpg);
}
#picture2{
width:512px;
height:349px;
background-image: url(http://images.wisegeek.com/young-calico-cat.jpg);
}
```

JS

```
function onMouseOver(e){
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

  switch(target.id){
    case "picture1":
    target.innerHTML = "Aphex Twin";
    break;
    case "picture2":
    target.innerHTML = "image2";
    break;      
  }

}
function onMouseOut(e){
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  target.innerHTML = "";
}

var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("dynamic-img"), len=imgs.length;

for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
  if(window.addEventListener){  //W3C
    imgs[i].addEventListener("mouseover",onMouseOver);
    imgs[i].addEventListener("mouseout",onMouseOut);
  }else if(window.attachEvent){  //IE<9
    imgs[i].attachEvent("onmouseover",onMouseOver);
    imgs[i].attachEvent("onmouseout",onMouseOut);
  }
}
```

Here is the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2jgbM/1/)

UPDATE: Note that you need to register the hover event handlers on those div after DOM is ready. Please put the script section at the bottom of the body. Document structure should looks like this:

```
<html>

<head>
<!--meta tag, style-->
<style>
<!--*****STYLE*****-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <!--*****DIV*****-->
    <div id="picture1" class="dynamic-img"></div>
    <div id="picture2" class="dynamic-img"></div>
    <!--*****JS*****-->
    <script src=""file.js></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't understand why this doesn't work. I copied it the same as have it here, I can see that it works on the jsfiddle you posted and yet, it just won't work in mine. I've tried it in Firefox, IE and Chrome. I don't any error messages from the consoles of any of the browsers but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I thought I might add my code `html: <div id="leftside">
        <h3>Featured Artist</h3>
        <div id="picture1" class="dynamic-img"></div>
        <h3>Featured Artist</h3>
        <div id="picture2" class="dynamic-img"></div>
     </div>`

Comment: `css #picture1{
 margin-left: 35px;
 height: 190px;
 width: 200px;
 background-image: url(../images/product/aphex.jpg);
 border: 3px solid #00306f;
}
#picture2{ 
 margin-left: 35px;
 height: 190px;
 width: 200px;
 background-image: url(../images/product/bjork.jpg);
 border: 3px solid #00306f;
}`

Comment: `js function onMouseOver(e)
{
 var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

 switch(target.id)
 {
  case "picture1":
  target.innerHTML = "Aphex Twin";
  break;
  case "picture2":
  target.innerHTML = "Bjork ";
  break;      
 }
}

Comment: function onMouseOut(e){
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  target.innerHTML = "";
}

var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("dynamic-img"), len=imgs.length;

for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
  if(window.addEventListener){  //W3C
    imgs[i].addEventListener("mouseover",onMouseOver);
    imgs[i].addEventListener("mouseout",onMouseOut);
  }else if(window.attachEvent){  //IE<9
    imgs[i].attachEvent("onmouseover",onMouseOver);
    imgs[i].attachEvent("onmouseout",onMouseOut);
  }
}

window.onload=onMouseOver;` Hope that's legible.

Comment: What's the order of the script block and #leftside div? You could try to put the script block at the bottom of the body (before </body></html>).

Comment: Oh. I've actually got my script in a separate file and I'm calling it in the head section of the html file. I almost certain that I'm calling the file correctly although nothing has happened from that file at all. It's fine to call more than one javascript file in a single html page isn't it. I have `<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>` then another one directly under it.

Comment: Answer is updated. Please refer it for more details.

Comment: You're welcome. Please select me as the answer if it's convenient to you.

Answer (score 0):

use event listeners. Here is a sample that should work for you.

```
addEventListener('mouseover', function() { document.getElementById( "picture1" ).innerHTML = "Aphex Twin"; } );
addEventListener('mouseout', function() { document.getElementById( "picture1" ).innerHTML = ""; } );
```

Comment: Hi, tried this as well and that wouldn't work either. I can't figure out if something is blocking the code or something.